# How can I shorten Jwplayer's script?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have a problem. My friends and I have a website. We add lots of movies to this website. We   use JwPlayer to play movies. But we always add script code with movie's url. For example:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://sinemall.net/wp-content/plugins/jw-player-plugin-for- wordpress/jwplayer.js'></script>
 </script>
 <div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

 <script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    sources: [{
       file: "http://www.website.com/..........720p.mp4",
           label: "720p HD",
          "default": "true"

       },{
       file: "http://www.website.com/..........1080p.mp4",
       label: "1080p HD"     
  }]
});
</script>
```

Is there a shorter way like:

```
 [embed]file: "http://www.website.com/..........720p.mp4",
           label: "720p HD",
          "default": "true"

       },{
       file: "http://www.website.com/..........1080p.mp4",
       label: "1080p HD"
 [/embed]
```

Or How do I Jwplayer main video player in WordPress?

Comment: ... looks pretty short to me.  And your example isn't any shorter really.

Comment: It is short but It is too long when we added lots of part in a movie.

Comment: This question doesn't really make a lot of sense. If you want to totally shorten it, use our WP plugin, that way the code you use is just in a shortcode block.

Comment: WP plugin will make it easier for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use wp plugin to shorten your code

> The JW Player WordPress Plugin enables you to configure and embed
>   audio and video content through your WordPress website. This is the
>   official JW Player plugin, developed by the JW Player team itself. Key
>   features include:
>
> Full JW6 support, including features of the Pro, Premium and Ads
>   editions. Convenient and reliable CDN hosting of the actual JW Player
>   assets. Smooth integration with the WordPress Media Manager (3.5
>   compatible). Embedding of external URLs, including YouTube videos and
>   RTMP streams. Creation an embedding of playlists using assets from the
>   Media Manager. Creation of multiple JW Player templates with distinct
>   layout/playback settings.

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403712-wordpress-plugin-quickstart

https://wordpress.org/plugins/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/